# Error in ResultSet Object

Tags: java, mysql

I'm thinking about the MVC application and for that and in the loading method of the lists that can be deleted with elements that are going to be chosen to make the query.

The classes associated with this are:

```
package modelo;
import java.sql.*;
 import controlador.*;

public class CargaMenus {

    public CargaMenus() {
        miconexion = new Conexion();
    }

    public String ejecutaConsultas() { //Va a devolver el nombre de las tareas en el conbobox

        Tareas miTarea = null;

        Connection accesoBBDD = miconexion.dameConexion();

        try {
            Statement secciones = accesoBBDD.createStatement();

            Statement descripciones = accesoBBDD.createStatement();

            rs = secciones.executeQuery("SELECT DISTINCTROW NOMTAREA FROM TAREAS");

            rs2 = descripciones.executeQuery("SELECT DISTINCTROW DESCTAREA FROM TAREAS");

            miTarea = new Tareas();

            miTarea.setNomtarea(rs.getString(1));

            miTarea.setDesctarea(rs2.getString(1));


            rs.close();
            rs2.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error en la conexión CARGAMENUS");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return miTarea.getNomtarea();
    }

    public Conexion miconexion;
    public ResultSet rs;
    public ResultSet rs2; 
    private String consulta = "SELECT DISTINCTROW NOMTAREA FROM TAREAS";
    private String consulta2 = "SELECT DISTINCTROW DESCTAREA FROM TAREAS";
}
```

and the class that executes the method and travel what is returned by the database is:

```
package controlador;

import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import modelo.CargaMenus;
import vista.Marco_Aplicacion2;
public class ControladorCargaMenus extends WindowAdapter {


    public ControladorCargaMenus(Marco_Aplicacion2 elmarco) {
        this.elmarco = elmarco;
    }


    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {


        obj.ejecutaConsultas();

        try {

            while(obj.rs.next()) {
                elmarco.secciones.addItem(obj.rs.getString(1));
            }
            while(obj.rs2.next()) {
                elmarco.paises.addItem(obj.rs2.getString(1));
            }
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    CargaMenus obj = new CargaMenus();
    private Marco_Aplicacion2 elmarco;
}
```

When I run the program, I only see a combobox of the 2 that I designed.

[image]

and the following error

[image]

I thought the problem would be my sql queries but I validated them and there is no problem when I run them in my mysql.

and when I only load one of the lists (the first one) commenting the lines associated with the second list, the application loads me even if it throws errors in the console

The link I'm learning about is [link of tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hjnJQrpBKiM&index=214&list=PLU8oAlHdN5BktAXdEVCLUYzvDyqRQJ2lk)
How could I do to load the lists?

Comment: move the rs.close() and rs2.close() calls after you where you attempt to use the result sets

Answer (score 0):

You should call `rs.next` before getting result.

```
if (rs.next()) {
  miTarea.setNomtarea(rs.getString(1));

  miTarea.setDesctarea(rs2.getString(1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is that you are not calling `rs.next()` before `rs.getString,` it is only called after the `ejecutaConsultas` method is run. Same applies to `rs2` usage.

Also you need to follow some best practices in your code such not exposing `ResultSet` to outside of your class and doing proper JDBC exception handling and closing of `ResultSet`s and`Connection`s.